# Why is there no French Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, languages, internationalization

There is the main [English Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com). There is a [Spanish Stack Overflow](https://es.stackoverflow.com). There is a [Portuguese Stack Overflow](https://pt.stackoverflow.com). There is a [Japanese Stack Overflow](https://ja.stackoverflow.com). There is a [Russian Stack Overflow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com).

Why is there no French Stack Overflow?

Comment: Why should there be a French one? Why do you focus on French? Why not Hebrew? Or Korean? Or Tagalog?

Comment: Because all ... *cough* ... some French people speak English.

Comment: Related on A51: [Internationalization 'State of the Stack' - Stack Overflow edition](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20987/131135)

Comment: @Glorfindel It is one of the around 3 different "explanations" what they gave, why they *don't want to grow*. I have a much better explanation, which doesn't look so as a false *excuse*: the SE is a successful startup not being able to handle its success and growth adequately.

Comment: @Oded Yes, Wikipedia exists on all of these languages. Some of them is small, some of them is bigger, but: all of them exists, and all of them is growing. Particularly in the case of the French Wiki, it is roughly 1/3 of the size of the main English site. If you had started the French SO  long ago, it would be now so big as the whole SE network.

Comment: I proposed one once, but it got closed and deleted.

Comment: Peoples in Quebec speak French, so French Stack Overflow should be proposed.

Comment: @user298438 not only in Quebec but in at least 40 countries and provinces ;) (but I disagree with this proposal and this is why : https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/311435/238720 )

Comment: Yeah. But Canada has French speaking-citizens, so we need them.

Comment: @user298438 Why only underlining the canadian's french speaking-citizens ? No matter for other french speakers ? ^^

Comment: We have matter in France for English Stack Overflow, so we also need them in France.

Comment: @Dona Summer see https://french.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Few hundred milion people in Africa speak French as their first language. They would be the primary target group for a French StackOverflow. Why do people focus just on France (or Canada) when it comes to French. Young developers from Africa would greatly profit from a French SO, just as their counterparts in Central and South America profit from Spanish and Portuguese SO.

Comment: D00d, wh47 5b0u7 5 574c|< 0v3rf10 n 1337?

Comment: Because French use Ordinateurs instead of computers. That just isn't supported by SO hardware :)

Comment: My guess is that there aren't French or German versions of SO because there English is in good standing and widely in use among programmers, compared to Portuguese, Spanish, Russian or Japanese. If this is actually a good or bad thing for French and German people I don't know. Maybe it's even just luck / bad luck. It could have happened if enough people would have been interested at the right time.

Comment: @cezar "Young developers from Africa would greatly profit from a French SO..." Then some of them must go to [area51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/) or another place like codidact maybe and get the thing started.

Comment: You got it the wrong way around. First there's a community, then the community can start a Stack. If there's no community willing to take that burden, there will be no Stack. Just like any other Area51 proposal, the community should already be there when the proposal is made.

Comment: Maybe SO should at least provide a translation tool (Google translate) within the pages, or as a part of the menu. This can reduce the differentiation of SO into so many sites.

Comment: @SK-the-Learner I support your idea. I'm from Spain but never used Spanish Stack Overflow since its limited (you cannot expect the same quality). A i18n approach will be better (actually this is how wikis work). You could create a question in any language (and then someone else translate it).

Comment: @cezar: Don't you mean *"...speak French as their first* ***foreign*** *language"*? (The first after their *Muttersprache*.)

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum no, French **is** their *Muttersprache* (mother tongue, for the non-Deutsch speakers), or at least one of them, if they grew up multi-lingual. Yay colonialism!

Answer (score 33):

L'avis d'un français parmi tant d'autres :p

First, French-speakers aren't helpless: there are already many active online French-speaking communities on computing since 1999 ([developpez.net](https://www.developpez.net/forums) for example, in which I am also actively involved).

Moreover, I think that good developers must practice English and I know it's not currently the case, but I've seen that since the increasing use of Stack Overflow or GitHub platforms (among many others recent platforms) around the world, the level of English is growing more and more in the young generation of French developers. And that's really good news. It's even a requirement of our institutions.

Finally, I think the first strength and maybe the main purpose of Stack Overflow is to provide the largest community of IT workers (with a maximum of represented countries), and allow different members of different countries to help each other. And to maintain this purpose, I think that creating a French Stack Overflow would be a really bad idea. Splitting the number of users and potential answers cannot be a good idea.

P.S: I'm not speaking for other French people or other French speakers, this is a personal point of view.

Comment: Please read the post linked in the top answer here. There was a proposal for a French Stack Overflow, but it was declined because Stack Exchange realized they don't have enough resources to support many non-English sites.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog I only gave my personal point of view about that (I'd prefer to add a comment in the first post but the limit is too short).

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog Don't believe for a moment that it had anything to do with the skills of their programmers! They can French, Russian, German, Hebrew beside of course English (and they don't need to know any language to translate the software to it). It is simply a boss decision, the programmers could create the site in a couple of hours any time. They don't do it, because  the boss says no. Why says the boss that? Uhm, it would be a more interesting question, I have a couple of theories but none of them is rational. A rational theory, well, that I don't have.

Comment: I wonder, what is "democratization of Stack Overflow"?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Maybe it's only a French expression and I'm sorry about that: that mean the increasing use of these platforms around the world (
no relation with the political sense of this word). I'll update my answer to change this expression.

Comment: Fair enough. Now the answer is clear. :)

Comment: I'm also French and I agree: people should learn the common language  (which happens to be English) to connect to a bigger collective brain (the IT part is a small part of the stack exchange). It's necessary to step out of the village mentality trap.

Comment: I just wanted to react to "First, French-speakers only aren't helpless: there are already many active online French-speaking communities on computing since 1999 (developpez.net for example, in which I am also actively involved)." IMHO, these communities are pretty bad overall (I really dislike developpez.net!), even worse in Spanish. In German, it's getting better but... still. Cannot say for other Europeans languages. Like most already said, learning the scientific and technical (and lingua franca) of your field is REALLY a must.

Comment: Another point you might be forgetting something subtly given by OP question: French is the language #5 in number of speakers worldwide, so not a dumb question.

Comment: @Paradox I never said that is a dumb question, but I said that I think that would be a bad idea and I explain why even if French was the second spoken language in the world. Splitting the number of users and potential answers cannot be a good idea.

Comment: @IdrissNeumann Do not feel assaulted, I was just stating that OP's question was not dumb, since all the four most represented languages worldwide had already a dedicated SE and French is ranked #5. End of story. Regarding your point, it is as well a good one and should be taken into account. Only thing that bothers me it that these two points do not have anything in common but they are strong points which seemed mostly primarily based on the point of view of each one of you. Regarding yours, consider that users on the English SE network are already splitted in communities. ;)

Comment: @IdrissNeumann ...and even you are already splitted between communities (SE, developpez.net, etc?). So, long story short, community fragmentation may not be the best approach to address comprehensively this type of problems.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. OP asked why there was a Spanish, Portuguese, Russian, etc. version of the site and no French one. And this doesn't address it at all.

Comment: @MrUpsidown The OP asked why there is no a French version of the site and I answered that I think it'd not be a good thing. It's an opinion-based answer but still an answer (and many people seems to agree with that).

Answer (score 23):

There has been a previous proposal (since deleted) for a French Stack Overflow, and its purpose was discussed at *https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1280/french-stackoverflow-translation-or-not*.  However, that link now gives "Page Not Found".

For the current status of Internationalization efforts for Stack Overflow you could review *[Internationalization 'State of the Stack' - Stack Overflow edition](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20987/internationalization-state-of-the-stack-stack-overflow-edition)*.